# Having problems with a model provided placeholder for dropdown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

So I have two cases that work independantly.

If I know I have model data in the dropdown, I use this code.

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Cars, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

HOWEVER, the problem with this, if `CarID` is `null` the first item on the list will be the pre selected in the dropdown.

And in another form, I use this one:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarID, "--Select a Car--", (SelectList)ViewBag.Cars, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

My Controller has this to provide the view data:

```
    ViewBag.Cars = new SelectList(db.Units, "CarID", "Name", model.CarID);
```

Is there ONE of these that I can use where it will have a placeholder ONLY if model data is not present to fill the spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second approach, you are using the helper method incorrectly,

It should be

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CarID,(SelectList)ViewBag.Cars,
                                           "Select one", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This will render the dropdown with a "Select one" option as the first (and default item), if nothing is pre selected (`model.CarID` is `null`). If `Model.CarID` has a valid value, It will select the corresponding option.

If you absolutely want to remove the "Select one" when `Model.CarID` is not null, you can write some javascript which executes on the document load (jQuery document ready :) ) to check the selected option and remove it as needed.

Comment: Ohhhhhh gotcha! Thanks. I have used it like that for a long time... never knew!

Comment: Well, actually I am still having a problem with it not showing up. With my enum seleectList it works fine, but with this one it isnt working.

Comment: When I have "Select One" in there, that shows up, but the one that it is isnt showing up.

Comment: My View model has the carID in it already, but I dont have the type Car Car in my view model. Could that be a problem?

Comment: so for this to work, do I HAVE to have model.CarID as the last argument when I make the new select list in the controller? I have a problem now where some drop downs are not working and others are but the code is the same. AND when I set a break point on the controller and inspect it, the selectList's "Selected Value" is there, but for some reason it doesnt carry over on the view.